# Determining conservation of isospin

Tags: conservation-laws, standard-model, subatomic, isospin-symmetry

I am trying to understand a worked example. The problem is to determine if all conservation laws are conserved in
$$
\pi^-+n \rightarrow K^++\Lambda^0
$$

The answer says that isospin is conserved, which I don't understand. Isospin for $\pi^-$ is $1$, the isospin for $n$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, for $K^+$ it is $\frac{1}{2}$ and for $\Lambda^0$ is is $0$.

How can it be conserved then? On the LHS we have $1+\frac{1}{2}$ and on the RHS we have $\frac{1}{2}+0$.

In short, I want to know: How to determine if isospin and its projection is conserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The isospin quantum number $I$ is not additive.  Isospins combine like angular momenta so in your example you have $I_\pi=1$ and $I_n=1/2$, so the possible values of isospin for the left hand side of your reaction is 
$1\otimes 1/2= 3/2\oplus 1/2$, i.e. the output channels must have either isospin quantum numbers $3/2$ or $1/2$.

The isospin projection number *is* additive; on the left you have the net projection $I_{\pi^-, 3}+ I_{n,3}$, and so on the right you must have the same net projection i.e. $I_{K^+,3}+I_{\Lambda^0,3}=I_{\pi^-, 3}+ I_{n,3}$, where $I_{a,3}$ is the isospin projection for particle $a$ along the isospin-3 axis.

Comment: Does the operator $\oplus$ have a name? I am not familiar with.

Comment: @C.E.  it's called "direct sum" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum ), just like $\otimes$ is called "direct product".